# Remove duplicates and keep ordering of unmodifiable class

Tags: java

My problem is that I am given a `List<T>` from which I need to remove duplicates and also keep the ordering.

I know I can use a `HashSet` to get rid of duplicates but it is based on `hashcode` and the class `T` does not implement it and I cannot modify it. And as I understand I will lose the ordering of my original list.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does "duplicate" mean in this context? Same reference (i.e. "==") or are they equal by `equals()`?

Comment: On what basis does two elements stand as duplicate?

Comment: I want to define the equality myself if possible

Comment: @Antoinecoding Exactly, how are you defining `equality`, if you are not overriding `equals`? And if you are overriding `equals`, then consider overriding `hashCode`.

Comment: I cannot modify T. But I think Vakh's solution enables me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, most of the Java data structures getting rid of duplicates rely on `hashcode`/`equals` methods.

Since you cannot modify the code of `T` and want to define the equality yourself, I suggest you create a wrapper of it where you can properly override the `hashcode`/`equals` methods:

```
public class MyT {
    private final T t;
    public MyT(T t) { this.t = t; }
    // + getter
    // + define hashcode and equals based on t
}
```

Afterwards, you can simply convert your `List<T>` into `List<MyT>`. Then you can use a `LinkedHashSet<MyT>` that removes duplicates based on `hashcode`/`equals` you just implemented and also keeps the ordering of your original list. Finally you can easily convert it back to a `List<T>` if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) class.

Comment: But `T` doesn't implement `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 1):

And, if your lists are small and you don't want to deal with hashing at all, you can always go with the O(n^2) solution and walk the list several times, looking for duplicates and removing them:

```
 public <T> void removeDups(List<T> listWithDups)
 {

    for(int i = 0; i < listWithDups.size(); i++)
    {
       T firstItem = listWithDups.get(i);

       for(int j = i+1; j < listWithDups.size(); j++)
       {
          T secondItem = listWithDups.get(j);

          if( (firstItem == null && secondItem == null) ||
                (firstItem != null && firstItem.equals(secondItem))
            )
          {
             listWithDups.remove(j);
             i--;
          }
       }
    }
 }
```